# ComputeIfAbsent wrong map size

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I have tried below code in order to have a unique id for each jj.

As far as I know, computeIfAbsent is thread-safe but:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService =
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        final Map<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Short>> threadSafeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        threadSafeMap.put("0", new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        threadSafeMap.put("1", new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            final int jj = i;
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                int                                key              = jj % 2;
                final ConcurrentMap<String, Short> idByName = threadSafeMap.get(String.valueOf(key));
                return idByName.computeIfAbsent(String.valueOf(jj), x -> (short) idByName.size());
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(threadSafeMap);
    }
```

Actual value:
{0={2=0, 4=0, 6=2, 8=3, 10=4}, 1={1=0, 3=0, 5=2, 7=3, 9=4}}

Expected value for example (due to concurrency):
{0={2=0, 4=1, 6=2, 8=3, 10=4}, 1={1=1, 3=0, 5=2, 7=3, 9=4}}

The problem is that I have with 2=0 and 4=0, which is wrong values should be unique!

btw using interger instead of short solve the issue!
Could you please help?

Comment: I confirm that the code as posted exhibits the observed behavior.  `Map<K,V>` has a naive default implementation of `computeIfAbsent()` which could cause this behavior, but it is irrelevant, because `ConcurrentHashMap` provides its own implementation. According to the documentation of `ConcurrentHashMap`, (or at any rate according to my interpretation of that documentation,) the OP should be receiving what he expects, and not what he observes. The implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()` is waaaay too complex for me to tell whether it is working as intended.

Comment: If anyone is interested at taking a look, [here's the source code for OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1691).

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong, as many different threads could be executing the same mapping function concurrently for different keys.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe but permits concurrent updates to the map. Some callers which are accessing similar parts of the underlying mapping tables may block while waiting for another thread to finish.

You won't find that `computeIfAbsent(someKey,mapFunc)` runs the mapping function for the same key twice, because it is an atomic operation for that key. So second or concurrent caller would see the value of the first call. However another `computeIfAbsent(anotherKey,mapFunc)` could be running at exactly the same time which is why your mapping function may evaluate `size()` to be same value for multiple keys.

The javadoc states:

> The supplied function is invoked exactly once per invocation of this method if the key is absent, else not at all.

> Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple.

If you wish to have unique values you could use `AtomicInteger` counter.

Comment: @MikeNatis The javadoc says "may be blocked" which implies that "some may not be blocked". Therefore other attempted computeIfAbsent operations on this map may not be blocked while another is running.

Comment: Concurrent access with a key not held in same sub-section of the map will be blocked.

Comment: I don't have same keys in my example, why size is not updated atomically with the insert in map?

Comment: The atomic insert applies to use of same key. But you have different keys so some of them may run concurrently. If you increase number of threads I'd expect to see more where "size()" is 0

Comment: ^^^ Okay, that's it.

Comment: Also worth citing: [“*Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including `size`, `isEmpty`, and `containsValue` are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads.*”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#:~:text=Bear%20in%20mind,%20other%20threads.)

Answer (score 1):

Something to note with ConcurrentHashMap is how the size of the map is calculated:

```
public int size() {
    long n = sumCount();
    return ((n < 0L) ? 0 :
            (n > (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE :
            (int)n);
}

final long sumCount() {
    CounterCell[] cs = counterCells;
    long sum = baseCount;
    if (cs != null) {
        for (CounterCell c : cs)
            if (c != null)
                sum += c.value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

These "counter cells" are updated upon a call to `addCount` internally. [At the end](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1775) of the `#computeIfAbsent` method we have:

```
if (val != null)
    addCount(1L, binCount);
return val;
```

However, before this code is reached, the lambda expression you are passing will have already been evaluated earlier on in the method. For instance, when we are first adding values, they will synchronize on a `ReservationNode`:

```
Node<K,V> r = new ReservationNode<K,V>();
synchronized (r) {
    if (casTabAt(tab, i, null, r)) { //compare-and-swap
        binCount = 1;
        Node<K,V> node = null;
        try {
            if ((val = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) //runs the mapping function
                node = new Node<K,V>(h, key, val);
            } finally {
                setTabAt(tab, i, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

src: [ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L1701-L1717)

The above code is quite suspect to me, and leaves me thinking that nothing would be truly blocked/synchronized on the creation phase here. Later on in the method (once the table entry exists), you'll see it doing `synchronized(f)` (the hash bucket) in order to compute/put the new values, which then causes the sequential insertion you see above.

So, those concurrent updates at the start (when we are first initializing the map) are not only capable of running in parallel, but even with proper synchronization in place could potentially retrieve a `0` for the Map's size before the end of the `#computeIfAbsent` call.

Comment: The important bit is line after `synchronized(r)` - the `if (casTabAt(tab, i, null, r)` means only one thread adds its version of `r` to the table and computes the first value, all other threads go around loop again and are stuck on another synchronized(r or f) or see the new computed value.

Comment: That explains the synchronization aspect around `ReservationNode`, but I believe it would still hold that another thread could enter the `synchronized` and compute the mapping function before the first thread reaches that `addCount`.

Comment: and why using integer instead of short works? :)